# E/SQLiteLog: (1) unrecognized token: ":"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception, android-sqlite

I'm trying to query a string where the value corresponds to a url address in sqlite/android studio, but it keeps throwing an exception:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) unrecognized token: ":"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project, PID: 4525
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ":" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM URLS_ITEMS WHERE title = Google AND url = http://www.google.com;
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (unrecognized token: ":" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM URLS_ITEMS WHERE title = Google AND url = http://www.google.com;)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1096)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:661)
```

And here's code snippet where the exception has been thrown:

```
public boolean isUrlAlreadyStored(String title, String url) {
        ArrayList<URLItem> urlDetailList = new ArrayList<URLItem>();
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_URLS_ITEMS + " WHERE title = " + title + " AND url = " + url + ";";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

I guess I should escape the character/token : but not sure how. I tried: url = url.replaceAll(":", ":") but apparently it's not the right way to do it.

Does anybody know how to query a value/string such as "https://www.stackoverflow.com"?

Answer (score 5):

you can add "'" single quotation for the string data type for SQLite.

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_URLS_ITEMS + " WHERE title = '" + title + "' AND url = '" + url + "';";
```

Answer (score 2):

The values of `title` and `url` are string literals and should be enclosed inside single quotes:

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_URLS_ITEMS + " WHERE title = '" + title + "' AND url = '" + url + "';";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

But the recommended and safe way to do this is to use placeholders `?` inside the statement and pass the values of `title` and `url` in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_URLS_ITEMS + " WHERE title = ? AND url = ?;";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] {title, url});
```